# Retorno de lista ordenada na BLL?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

No meu projeto uso o `EF6`, uso repositórios genéricos e na minha camada `BLL` eu tenho a classe `ClienteBLL`, que é uma classe que tem os métodos de implementação logica da classe.

Em um dos métodos eu retorno uma lista que recebe todos os clientes do banco e depois faça uma ordenação

Método:

```
public IList<ClienteDTO> TodosClientes()
{
   List<ClienteDTO> lista = clienteRepo.BuscarTodos().ToList();    
   lista.Sort(delegate (ClienteDTO a, ClienteDTO b) { return a.nome.CompareTo(b.nome); });

   return lista;
}
```

**Minha duvida:** É errado ordenar a lista dessa forma? Se sim, o que recomenda?

Achei uma maneira bem melhor: [How to Sort a List by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Então com base na resposta do link eu fiz assim:

```
public IList<ClienteDTO> TodosClientes()
{
    return clienteRepo.BuscarTodos().OrderBy(o => o.nome).ToList();
}
```

Agora não tenho duvidas que está certo!

Meu repositório genérico:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        GdPContext contexto = new GdPContext();


        public IQueryable<T> BuscarTodos()
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Buscar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicado)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>().Where(predicado);
            return query;
        }

        public void Adicionar(T entity)
        {
            contexto.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Excluir(T entity)
        {
            contexto.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public void Editar(T entity)
        {
            contexto.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(entity);
        }

        public void Salvar()
        {
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            contexto.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As duas formas que você está utilizando não são recomendável, porque, está fazendo errado, você deveria fazer o `OrderBy` em um método genérico na sua classe  de repositório e utilizar para ordernar na sua SQL, o que está acontecendo é que você materializa a informação e depois ordena na memória isso causa baixo desempenho.

Comment: Amigo, se não for pedir muito tem como explicar melhor a parte de ordenar na SQL

Comment: Eu preciso da implementação do seu Repositório, porque ai eu consigo explicar o que poderia ser feito. Na explicação da SQL é porque você antes de materializar o dado (`ToList()`, `First()`, etc) poderia adicionar o OrderBy para que na sua SQL esteja presente a ordenação e com o eu relatei não em memória.

Comment: Entendi! Editei a pergunta e coloquei o repositório genérico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na implementação da sua classe de `interface` (`IGenericRepository<T>`) crie um outro método com a seguinte assinatura:

```
IQueryable<T> BuscarTodos<Tkey>(Expression<Func<T,Tkey>> orderBy);
```

e logo após implementar na sua classe `GenericRepository<T>`, dentro do método faça o seguinte código que é ideal e a ordenação feita direta na instrução `SQL` e os dados vindo ordenados da sua *tabela*:

```
public IQueryable<T> BuscarTodos<Tkey>(Expression<Func<T, Tkey>> orderBy)
{
    return contexto.Set<T>()
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .OrderBy(orderBy); 
}
```

Para utilizar esse código:

```
clienteRepo.BuscarTodos(o => o.nome).ToList();
```

O método que foi adicionado `AsNoTracking()` é mais uma otimização, onde os dados retornados só serão lidos e não mantidos em contexto, ou seja, os dados são somente leitura, isso é bom para mostrar dados que não serão nesse momento alterado.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Isso vai me ajudar muito daqui pra frente.